# Error in generalized linear mixed model in SPSS

Tags: error-handling, spss

I'm doing a generalized linear mixed model with SPSS. **Outcome:** Wellbeing (MmDWohlbefinden_umkodiert), **Fixed effects:** Intervention (Pre/Post), Symptoms occurring when intervention was applied (BPSD), **Random effect:** Individuals (repeated measure).

**My question:** Why does the following error occur: “The final Hessian matrix is not positive definite although all convergence criteria are satisfied. The procedure continues despite this warning. Subsequent results produced are based on the last iteration. Validity of the model fit is uncertain.” And what can I do about it?

These is my codes:

```
GENLINMIXED
/FIELDS TARGET=MmDWohlbefinden_umkodiert TRIALS=NONE OFFSET=NONE
/TARGET_OPTIONS DISTRIBUTION=GAMMA LINK=IDENTITY
/FIXED  EFFECTS=Intervention_K1 BPSD_K1 USE_INTERCEPT=TRUE
/RANDOM EFFECTS=ID USE_INTERCEPT=FALSE COVARIANCE_TYPE=VARIANCE_COMPONENTS SOLUTION=FALSE
/BUILD_OPTIONS TARGET_CATEGORY_ORDER=ASCENDING INPUTS_CATEGORY_ORDER=ASCENDING MAX_ITERATIONS=100
CONFIDENCE_LEVEL=95 DF_METHOD=RESIDUAL COVB=MODEL PCONVERGE=0.000001(ABSOLUTE) SCORING=0
SINGULAR=0.000000000001
/EMMEANS_OPTIONS SCALE=ORIGINAL PADJUST=LSD.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not a code problem. It is a model specification / statistical problem. When the Hessian is negative, this means that your model is not adequate to your data.

Some advice on how to fix this issue can be found in: https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/gking/files/help.pdf